# Specified Child already has a parent android, without any line number of crash in my code

Tags: java, android, crash, illegalstateexception

I got this crash in crashalytics in my app mostly in phones having Android 9 (Pie). The crash is IllegalStateException. Crash report doesn't have line number of crash. I already checked places where I use adView and called removeView on their parent views. Attaching stack trace for further information.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner + 5034 (ViewGroup.java:5034)
android.view.ViewGroup.addView + 4865 (ViewGroup.java:4865)
android.view.ViewGroup.addView + 4822 (ViewGroup.java:4822)
android.widget.PopupWindow.createDecorView + 1409 (PopupWindow.java:1409)
android.widget.PopupWindow.preparePopup + 1356 (PopupWindow.java:1356)
android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation + 1198 (PopupWindow.java:1198)
android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation + 1170 (PopupWindow.java:1170)
android.widget.Editor$HandleView.updatePosition + 4735 (Editor.java:4735)
android.widget.Editor$PositionListener.onPreDraw + 3214 (Editor.java:3214)
android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw + 977 (ViewTreeObserver.java:977)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals + 2483 (ViewRootImpl.java:2483)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal + 1468 (ViewRootImpl.java:1468)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run + 7208 (ViewRootImpl.java:7208)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run + 1004 (Choreographer.java:1004)
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks + 816 (Choreographer.java:816)
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame + 751 (Choreographer.java:751)
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run + 990 (Choreographer.java:990)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback + 873 (Handler.java:873)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 99 (Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop + 193 (Looper.java:193)
android.app.ActivityThread.main + 6692 (ActivityThread.java:6692)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 493 (RuntimeInit.java:493)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 858 (ZygoteInit.java:858)
```